# Can't withdraw funds from a Contract

Tags: contract-development, zksync, withdrawal

I've deployed a contract for education purposes and used it.
The contract address: 0x3Fe77339866AB535Fe4f8D1F2Ee1a1a49658AeBf

You can see the contract code on zkscan but i will put the relevant part below:

```
constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, 'Only the owner can call this function.');
        _;
    }

    function deploy(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 initialSupply
    ) public payable {
        require(msg.value == deployFee, 'Deploying a token requires a fee.');
        MyERC20Token newToken = new MyERC20Token(
            name,
            symbol,
            initialSupply * (10 ** 18),
            msg.sender
        );
        emit TokenCreated(address(newToken), msg.sender, name, symbol);
    }

    function setDeployFee(uint256 newFee) public onlyOwner {
        deployFee = newFee;
    }

    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
```

When i check the owner of the contract from zkscan my address matches up. But when i try to use the withdraw function i get this error:

```
cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x091973604fBbEb8659C23b6CC5d55e6543fc2244","to":"0x3Fe77339866AB535Fe4f8D1F2Ee1a1a49658AeBf","data":"0x3ccfd60b","type":0,"accessList":null}, error={"code":-32603,"message":"Internal JSON-RPC error.","data":{"code":3,"message":"execution reverted","data":"0x","cause":null}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.0)
```

Any experienced devs out here that can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say for sure, but most likely the transaction fails (or is estimated to fail) because you are issuing the transaction from some non-owner account.

The function uses a modifier `onlyOwner`. That modifier checks that the caller is the owner of the contract. If you try to call that function from any other wallet/address than the contract owner, the transaction fails.

Two other notes:

1. Please provide the link to the contract, not just its address. Difficult to know in which network it is
2. I hope you're using a testnet, instead of some mainnet with real assets.